Pushforward measure for Radon Nikodym equation
Consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ and another probability measure $\mu$, on that same space, given by
$$\mu(A)=\int_A f(\omega)  \mathbb{P}(d\omega)$$
Now let $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ be a random variable mapping to $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$.
I am interested in the pushforward measure $\mu_X$ and want to express it in terms of the pushforward measure $\mathbb{P}_X$.
From the above equation we know that $\mu \ll \mathbb{P}$. Does this also imply that $\mu_X \ll  \mathbb{P}_X$? If that was the case, we could write again (due to the Radon Nikodym theorem):
$$\mu_X(F)=\int_F g(x) \mathbb{P}_X(dx)$$
If all of this is possible, what would be the connection between $f$ and $g$? Is it also possible to obtain the second equation somehow directly through the change of variables formula?

This is a basic application of integration of image measure. Formally, this can be stated in the following way:
Result: Let $(\Omega_1,\mathscr F_1,\mathbb P) $ be a probability space. Let $\mu\ll \mathbb P ,$ that is, there exists a non-negative, real-valued measurable function $h$ such that $\mathrm d\mu=h~\mathrm d\mathbb P. $ If $X$ is a random object $X:\Omega_1\to \Omega_2$ where $(\Omega_2,\mathscr F_2)$ is a measurable space, then $$\mu\circ X^{-1}\ll \mathbb P\circ X^{-1},\tag 1\label 1$$ and $$\frac{\mathrm d\mu\circ X^{-1}}{\mathrm d\mathbb P\circ X^{-1}}=\mathbf E[h\mid X=x].\tag 2\label 2$$
$\eqref 1$ is easy to check: Let $A\in\mathscr F_2$ and $\mathbb P\circ X^{-1}(A) =0.$ This means $\mathbb P\left(X^{-1}(A)\right) =0$ and by assumption of $\mu\ll \mathbb P, ~\mu\left(X^{-1}(A)\right)=\mu\circ X^{-1}(A)=0.$
As for $\eqref 2,$ note $g:=\frac{\mathrm d\mu\circ X^{-1}}{\mathrm d\mathbb P\circ X^{-1}}$ is a real-valued $\mathscr F_2/\mathscr B_\mathbb R$ measurable function on $\Omega_2.$  Therefore on $A\in\mathscr F_2, $ using integration of image measure,
\begin{align}\int_A\mathrm d\left(\mu\circ X^{-1}\right)&=\int_A g~\mathrm d\left(\mathbb P\circ X^{-1}\right)\\\implies \int_{X^{-1}(A)}\mathrm d\mu &=\int_{X^{-1}(A)}g\circ X~\mathrm d\mathbb P\\\implies \int_B h~\mathrm d\mathbb P &=\int_B g\circ X~\mathrm d\mathbb P, ~~\forall~B\in X^{-1}(\mathscr F_2);\tag 3\label 3\end{align} $\eqref 3$ implies that $g\circ X\in\mathbf E[h\mid X].$
$\blacksquare$
--
Reference:
$\rm[I]$ A Graduate Course on Statistical Inference, Bing Li, G. Jogesh Babu, Springer Science$+$ Business, $2019, $ sec. $1.14.$

Could you explicate more the last point (3)?

@kjetil, it shows $g\circ X$ is the version of the conditional expectation of $h$ given $X.$ So $g$ is $\mathbf E[h\mid X=x].$

In my previous comment, in place of "the", it would be " a". If more clarification is needed, ping me @kjetil.

@User1865345 so this whole argument seems to only work if $X$ has an inverse, i.e., if it is bijective (or injective since I think we only need left-inverse). But this seems to be a very big restriction for a random variable. So my question: If we have a RV that is not injective/bijective, and hence has no inverse, can we still reason about the absolute continuity of the pushforward measure?

Could you tell where we needed the condition of injectivity of $X$?

@User1865345 I think in the line above equation (3)
